# Xcode thousands of memory leaks in system libraries

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I did a instrumentation run on my app to check for memory leaks since it has been several months (at least) since I last checked, and I had added a new feature to my app and refactored some code. When I started the run, everything looked good with the first check (main view controller loaded and it has 6 buttons, a label, and 6 custom UI views that are essentially just labels with some images), but the second check blew my mind, saying I had 1460 new leaks. This seemed really high when all I had done in the app was press a button that pushed a second view controller (albeit not a simple one, but it wasn't doing anything fancy either).

Taking a look at the list of leaks, only 7 were marked as being my app's fault, with the other 1453 being the following system libraries:

- AppSupport
- BackBoardServices
- BaseBoard
- CFNetwork (how? I'm not even doing any networking...)
- ColorSync
- CoreGraphics
- CoreUI
- Foundation (probably ~300 leaks)
- FrontBoardServices
- GraphicsServices
- ImageIO
- ManagedConfiguration
- PrototypeTools
- QuartzCore
- UIFoundation
- UIKitCore (~700 leaks, looked like about half)
- UIKitServices
- libAccessibility.dylib
- libnetwork.dylib
- libsystem_pthread.dylib
- vimage

The more I do in the app, the more system libraries appear, and I can easily achieve several thousand leaks.

Looking at all the different stack traces, the curious thing is that about half of them (from all the random traces I looked at) have the same top four or five calls starting with the `lookUpImpOrForward` or `_objc_msgSend_uncached` functions, as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image: Instruments memory leak run]

When I look at the leaks caused by my app, they all have those five functions at the top of their stack trace, with my app's functions just below them. When I double click on my functions in the stack traces to take a look at the lines of code that allocated the leaked memory, I am taken to lines like

```
label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

or

```
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(bottomBar.frame.origin.x + 70,
                            bottomBar.frame.origin.y);
```

the first of which should be perfectly safe since I'm not doing anything fancy memory-wise in that class, and I have no clue how the second can possibly even be involved in a memory leak since it doesn't deal with any pointers.

To try and narrow down the cause, I ran again and pushed a different button that took me to a view controller that does nothing when loaded and only contains a navigation bar, 6 buttons (4 with images), and 3 labels - pretty minimal basic stuff. Still, I get 828 new leaks on the check after pressing the button.

Going even further, I created a brand new single view application project in Xcode, and duplicated the first view controller. I put a button on the first view controller that had a show segue to the second, and I put a label on the second view controller. You can find the code at https://github.com/AdamNEvans/LeakySampleApp. Running this in instruments gives me a whopping 237 memory leaks after pushing the second view controller. How?!?!?

I don't remember ever seeing nearly this many leaks when doing memory leak instrumentation runs in the past. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong that is causing at least some of these leaks, but the fact that there are so many and so many don't include any of my code makes me think that I'm either creating objects incorrectly in a bunch of different places (I'm not sure how I can screw up `alloc` and `init` calls), or a bug was introduced into the system libraries and is wreaking havoc (my guess would be something in those common five functions at the top of lots of the stack traces).

90% of the leaks are under 1K, so the app can survive for quite a while with these leaks, but it still concerns me since this is a utility app that people can potentially spend hours in.

I have ARC on and am using Xcode 10.2.1 while running my app on a physical iPad Air 2 with iOS 12.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: “I created a brand new single view application project in Xcode”. Excellent. Can you post a reduced version of that so it can be downloaded and examined?

Comment: What do you mean by reduced version? The project has zero new lines of code from the default, just the extra label, button, segue, and view controller in the default storyboard. It can't really get more reduced than that. Also, how do you add something to a question that isn't an image?

Comment: I’m asking you to upload it to Dropbox or github or similar.

Comment: Two things: 1. Before you worry about system “leaks” make sure that none of your objects are leaking. One leaked object of yours can lead to lots of framework related issues. 2. Since you’re writing Objective-C, have you run the static analyzer (“Build” » “Analyze” or shift+command+B)? It’s remarkably good at identifying issues. Again, don’t worry about framework stuff until you have a clean bill of health from the static analyzer.

Comment: @Rob I just ran the static analyzer, and it found less than ten leaks, all dealing with Core Graphics, and only in functions that were never called during my testing. The only issue it found that could affect the tests I ran was that I'm not using localized strings in my project, which I surely hope isn't causing thousands of leaks...

Comment: @Rob I've fixed all the leaks the analyzer found, and I'm still getting the 800+ leaks when going to the simpler view controller, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @Aderis you're not crazy. This is definitely an issue with the iOS core libraries (specifically, UIKitCore, as far as I can tell). I've created a standard single-view app, totally vanilla, with no buttons. Run it on an iOS 12.2 simulator -> hundreds of leaks within seconds. Likewise on a real device, but it varies; occasionally you'll only get 1 or 2 leaks, other times it will be more. Switch to an iOS 12.0 simulator, and the leaks totally disappear. Definitely a bug, and not your fault! I'll be submitting a radar to Apple later. Please do the same with your findings.

Answer (score 1):

While testing my demo apps, I also noticed a bunch of leaks. Associated with completely different system libraries.
For example, segments of ImageIO code that render the image.

There is nothing to leak (there are only about 10 lines of code, Yes, I know about CFRelease functions and I use their, but it does not help).

I also noticed that the same project running on a real device-does not detect leaks, but the same project on the simulator gets leaks.

Leaks exist even in singleView projects where everything is implemented in storyboard.

P.S.
Every year Apple releases a new operating system and a new version of the language, a new API.
God, what's a race like this for ? As a result, they spend time on AR / Metal and stuff but forget about the basic tools for developers, for example Xcode which with sixth version of has very low rating, often buggy…